# How do you printf _ExtInt without using casts?

Tags: c, integer, printf, clang, extint

I was wondering how you could `printf` `_ExtInt`s in clang without using casts. Something like this:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    _ExtInt(13) foo = 100;
    printf("%???", foo);
}
```

With casts, it would look like this (this is not what I want):

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    _ExtInt(32) foo = 100;
    printf("%d", (int) foo);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The `_ExtInt` types are a new feature in Clang (LLVM) as described at [The New Clang `_ExtInt` Feature Provides Exact Bitwidth Integer Types](http://blog.llvm.org/2020/04/the-new-clang-extint-feature-provides.html),  published 2020-04-21 (3 days ago as I type).

If `_ExtInt(32)` is a 32-bit signed integer type and `int` is a 32-bit signed integer type, then you can use `%d` and no cast in both calls to `printf()`.  The arguments after the format are subject to the integer promotion rules, so I expect that both `_ExtInt(13)` and `_ExtInt(32)` would be converted to `int` as they are passed to `printf()`, so the correct conversion specifier is `%d`.

If you use bigger types, up to `_ExtInt(64)`, you can probably use `%lld` on any machine (or `%ld` on a 64-bit machine).  If you go bigger than that, you are on your own; you need an implementation of `printf()` that knows how to handle `_ExtInt` types, and that will probably have notations in the format that allow for the length to be specified.  For example, hypothesizing wildly, it might support `%<700>d` for a signed `_ExtInt(700)`.

Comment: [It appears that these extended integer types are not subject to integer promotion](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#extended-integer-types)

Comment: @exnihilo: But the document says "Unary `+`, `-`, and `~` operators typically will promote operands to int. Doing these promotions would inflate the size of required hardware on some platforms, so extended integer types aren’t subject to the integer promotion rules in these cases."  That's fine; it's not clear to me that `printf()` is any of those operators, though.  I imagine that the rules apply to the shift operators, and the bitwise operators too.  It also says "Extended integer types align with existing calling conventions", which I take to mean "they work sanely with `printf()`" too.

Comment: I wondered at that too, but it didn't seem clear to me from the documentation. Yet the [page you linked to](http://blog.llvm.org/2020/04/the-new-clang-extint-feature-provides.html) also says: "_The _ExtInt types as implemented do not participate in any implicit conversions or integer promotions,...._"

Comment: That's a blog page, and not as precise as what you found. And what you found doesn't cover all the operators sensibly — though it does specify that you have to have the same size on either side of an operator like `+`, so you can't add an `_ExtInt(8)` and an `_ExtInt(12)` without explicit casts. The "calling conventions" comment and surrounding text implies that `_ExtInt(13)` will be lengthened to an appropriate larger size (16 or 32 bits, probably — and I strongly suspect 32 bits for conventional chips, not the FGPA chips that it is targeted at). There is a lot left unsaid in both references.

Comment: If the function had a prototype that said `_ExtInt(21)` (for Unicode characters, for example), then you'd be able to pass an `_ExtInt(21)` to that function, and no other type.  An `_ExtInt(16)` would not be implicitly promoted to `_ExtInt(21)`.  But `printf()` and variadic functions like require types shorter than `int` to be converted to `int`.  Either you can't pass `_ExtInt(21)` to `printf()` at all without a cast, or it gets promoted to `int` (presuming 32-bit `int`).  I think that the "existing calling conventions" comment means you can.  But I've not experimented with the real thing.

Comment: That makes sense, and you are probably right; it's just that I usually follow a "when in doubt, make an explicit conversion" policy ;)

Comment: This seems good, but I'm not sure how to make custom printfs for those...

Comment: @Xilpex: Neither am I — let me know when you find out how to do it.  Hex is easy; decimal is not — at least, that's my immediate take on the topic.  Maybe you do something like take the value modulo 1,000,000,000 and divide by the same to process 9 decimal digits at a time, using regular 32-bit `int` to deal with the value between 0 and 999,999,999.  Of course, that generates the answer in reverse, so you have to worry about recursion, or something.  Like I said, I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

Use a wide type by forming a `long` product.  `int` may be 16-bit.  `long` is at least 32.  `long long` is at least 64.

```
_ExtInt(13) foo1 = 100;
printf("%d\n", 1 * foo);
// or
printf("%d\n", 0 + foo);

_ExtInt(32) foo2 = 100;
printf("%ld\n", 1L * foo);
// or
printf("%ld\n", 0L + foo);
```

Comment: This seems like a good way to avoid a cast; the extended integer types may not be subject to integer promotion, but they obey the usual arithmetic conversions.

Comment: @Xilpex: you won't be able to process `_ExtInt(700)` with a conventional implementation of `printf()`.  You will have to look at what the libraries provided support — there'll need to be special documentation.  They may be waiting on the WG14 (standard C committee) to provide guidance.